# Creating Flex Filters

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, wcs

According to the Oracle documentation regarding the creation of custom flex filters, in order to implement a custom filter, a class extending AbstractFlexFilter is needed. The class is located in com.openmarket.gator.flexfilters package, but there is on information on where this package is located.

Does anyone know where the jar containing this specific package is located?

[Link to documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcs/develop/GUID-A7491588-7245-49E3-B847-2173B2FC401C.htm#WBCSD1631)